# SharePoint Network Share Access Denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I'm building a web part for our SharePoint that needs to read file and folder names from a network share. However, I get an access denied error when I try to use

```
Directory.GetDirectories(path);
```

I've done some research on how to fix this, the general consensus is to either use RunWithElevatedPrivileges or impersonate the current logged in user. Unfortunately everything I've tried has failed. I have tried all of the following to no avail:

1. [Impersonating the user](http://www.sharepointdeveloperhq.com/2009/04/how-to-programmatically-impersonate-users-in-sharepoint/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164626/impersonate-as-different-user-inside-the-webpart-code)
2. [Setting the ASP.NET app pool to classic mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539142/impersonation-not-working-network-share) (Breaks all of sharepoint)
3. [Changing the trust level for SharePoint to full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204149/accessing-a-remote-file-with-a-sharepoint-web-part)  (Doesn't seem to affect anything)
4. [Giving the Network Service permission to the network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432556/possible-to-give-network-service-on-one-computer-permission-to-a-directory-on)
5. Making a symbolic link on the SharePoint machine that points to the network share

Any suggestions on what to do? I'm at the end of my rope.

Comment: Create a domain account and have that account run the application pool for SharePoint.  Then give that account access to the network share.

Comment: changed the app pool identity. Now Sharepoint gives me a 503 Service unavailable. Did I miss permissions somewhere?

Comment: In the security policy make sure the domain account has `Log on as a batch job` permissions.

Comment: What kind of path are you using? `\\server\share\file.ext`?

Comment: @JohnSaunders yes, exactly. \\server\\share\folder